# TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined in Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to redirect to another page after success callback but I am getting this error **TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined**

```
 this.http.post('http://localhost:3030/users', userDetails).subscribe(function 
 successCallback(response) {
  this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
   }, function errorCallback(response) {
      // response with status 500
  }) ;
```

Comment: you should define ```navCtrl``` , full code please.

Comment: is navCtrl initiated?

Comment: Arrow function to the rescue

Answer (score -1):

Use arrow function `=>` like this -

```
this.http.post('http://localhost:3030/users', userDetails).subscribe(successCallback(response) => {
  this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
   }, errorCallback(response) => {
      // response with status 500
  }) ;
```

Comment: Downvoter, Can you please tell the problem here in answer

Comment: "[ts] Expected 0-3 arguments, but got 4" I am getting this issue

Comment: This must be coming from somewhere else